# standard gestures does not trigger gesture event on iOS, fire monkey delphi xe6

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, gestures, delphi-xe6

I don't know what I've done but Standard gestures does not work on my project.
I've added a gesture manager and assign it to a ttabcontrol, selected left and right gestures from standard gestures. When I run the project gesture does not work, onGesture event of the ttabcontrol is not fired.

When I assign gesture manager to form nothing is changed.

When I try it with a simple application it works well.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please include the `delphi` tag to your delphi related questions

Comment: Thanks for the warning Sir Rufo

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the tabcontrol.TabPosition to Dots.